# "A server with the specified hostname cannot be found" error for downloading apps on Mac App Store

Tags: ios, macos, dns, app-store, app-store-connect

Frequently I face this issue where whenever I pressed get button to download anything from Mac App store, A message would pop up saying *"A server with the specified hostname cannot be found"*. I didn't find this issue published anywhere as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue hence I wanted to share this with other people.

I was told to wait for 10-20 minutes and retry on the App Store but that failed for me. I changed my wifi form 5G to 2.4G thinking maybe it was a band issue.

#### What worked for me was:

1. Go to System Preferences
2. Go to Network Preferences
3. Click advanced options
4. Click DNS settings
5. Click the + (plus) sign
6. Add `1.1.1.1`
7. Similarly add `8.8.8.8`

[image: A picture of how your preference should look]

This worked for me and I hope this works for you too. You can remove these once you're able to download the app you want from app Store. After removing also you'll be able to download apps.

Comment: So basically it's a DNS issue. 1.1.1.1 the CloudFlare DNS; 8.8.8.8 is Google's. If this is at home, I'm guessing this might just as well have been resolved by restarting your cable modem, as that would reestablish a link to your DNS.

Comment: I did try that. I hoped it'd make it right too but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Make a network setting refresh. Simply go to /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ and remove the following files, but don't empty the trashcan.

- com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
- com.apple.network.identification.plist
- com.apple.wifi.message-tracer.plist
- NetworkInterfaces.plist
- preferences.plist

After this, make a restart and your network will get fixed.